# Programmatically deploy a web application via a Windows form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms, web-deployment

I have an ASP.NET web application and I've been using the web deploy via VS to deploy my application to Azure, however in this scenario the clients will host my application on their own servers so I'd like to design a desktop application that would allow me to configure settings (connection string primarily), update the web.config and then deploy the application to their server.

The connection string needs to be changed because they have their **own** databases.

Is this possible? If so are there any suggestions on approaching this and or any alternative methods or am I just over-thinking things(which I usually do) and going in the completely wrong direction?

Comment: Have you looked into [creating a deployment package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I'll look into this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to design a desktop application that would allow me to
>   configure settings (connection string primarily), update the
>   web.config and then deploy the application to their server.

If you know the settings, you can make changes in your config file and publish the application.

But if you want to let the customer change settings after publishing on their server, instead of creating a Windows Application to change settings, you can create some pages/controllers in your web application and configure them to work only local by checking [`Request.IsLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal(v=vs.110).aspx). This way that part of application will be accessible only on server.

The server administrator can use the web application on the server to change settings.

You can also make it more secure by using an authentication provider which stores username/password hash in a file. If you made it secure you also can let the administrator work with that part remotely.

For more information about deployment of web applications take a look at:

- [Web Deployment Overview for Visual Studio and ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is there a simple way to configure web.config without using VS? the idea is for colleagues to handle configuration and setup (They aren't programmers so they won't have IDE's)

Comment: Config files are in text format and can be simply edited using a text editor like notepad. Working with configuration is job of experienced users who know about connection strings and so on. Using a wizard or a settings form just make the job more friendly for you or administrator to perform initial settings.

Comment: Alright thank you, I can't +1 due to lack of reputation :(

Comment: No problem, you will gain reputations soon :)